# Правильность написания функции

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, рекурсия

**Есть задача**

> Реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, которая выполняет глубокое копирование объектов.

```
 const data = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: {
    key: 'innerValue',
    innerKey: {
      anotherKey: 'anotherValue',
    },
  },
};
```

И условие для проверки:

```
// result имеет такую же структуру, как и data
const result = cloneDeep(data);
 
// Но внутри другие объекты
result.key2 !== data.key2; // true
result.key2.innerKey !== data.key2.innerKey; // true
```

**Решение**

```js
const data = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: {
    key: 'innerValue',
    innerKey: {
      anotherKey: 'anotherValue',
    },
  },
};

const cloneDeep = obj => {
  const clone = {};
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  for (const value of values) {
    if ((typeof value) === 'object') {
      Object.assign(clone, obj);
      cloneDeep(value);
    } else {
      Object.assign(clone, obj);
    }
  }
  return clone;
}

const result = cloneDeep(data);
console.log(result);
```

> То есть я получаю полностью изолированный объект, изменяя значение в полученном, не затрагивая в исходном.

Но при проверке условий получаю "false". Или же стоит воспринимать буквально **"Но внутри другие объекты"?**. При изменении значений соответственно получаю "true".

Comment: зачем постоянно делать `Object.assign(clone, obj);` в цикле?

Comment: А ну да верно,  в цикле это строка вообще не нужна, лишь после полного "погружения" нужно слияние

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведенная функция `cloneDeep` НЕ делает глубокое копирование. По сути ее вызов сводится к одному вызову [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Клонированный объект возвращается с помощью `return`, однако возвращаемое значение игнорируется всегда, кроме самого первого вызова.

Вместо этого, оно должно было записываться по указанному ключу в объекте-клоне.

Кроме того `typeof obj === 'object'` не охватывает, например, функции, которые в этом случае не копируются, а продолжают по ссылке передаваться.

Также ломаются сложные объекты, вроде массивов, сетов, и т.д. так как клон - это всегда обычный объект.

Для простого случая, когда игнорируются сложные классы объектов, алгоритм может быть следующим:

1. если передали не объект - возвращаем как есть
2. создаем пустой объект-клон
3. для каждого клюя в исходном объекте присваиваем значением глубокую копию значения из исходного объекта.

Пример:

```js
const data = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: {
    key: 'innerValue',
    innerKey: {
      anotherKey: 'anotherValue',
    },
  },
};

const cloneDeep = obj => {
  if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;

  const clone = {};
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);
  for (const [key, val] of entries) {
    clone[key] = cloneDeep(val);
  }
  return clone;
}

const result = cloneDeep(data);
console.log(result);


// Но внутри другие объекты
console.log(result.key2 !== data.key2); // true
console.log(result.key2.innerKey !== data.key2.innerKey); // true
```